# Can someone explain the resolutions in Rachmaninoff Prelude in C# Minor?

Tags: theory, piano, cadence

I started to learn the Rachmaninoff Prelude in C# Minor ([Op. 3 No. 2](https://imslp.org/wiki/Morceaux_de_fantaisie%2C_Op.3_(Rachmaninoff%2C_Sergei))). Until recently I have had not much experience with music theory, except for the very basic things.
In order to remember the piece better, I would like to understand some parts better from a theoretical point of view.

Take for example the last two triplets in bar 17. The last one is a `c# minor`, so the triplet before occurs to me to be a dominant seventh, that is `g#`, to resolve in the classic way of `V-I`.

Bar 21 starts with `A` and ends with `A`. The final resolution to the `A` seems to be a `d` diminished seventh chord. Why has this to be a `d`? What is the reason or explanation behind this?

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you posted the part of the score in question.

Comment: Are you talking about this bar? https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAdnq.png Can you clarify what do you mean by "why has this to be a d"? And why the emphasis on *has*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chord on the third beat of m. 21 is `G#dim7` (over a pedal `A`). Rachmaninoff happens to have left out the `B`, because the note isn't necessary to his harmonic or melodic purposes and doesn't fit the voice leading. `G#dim`, of course, is the `vii` chord in `A`, and serves a standard dominant function.

The clue that it is not `Ddim` is the spelling. `Ddim` would be spelled with `Ab` rather than `G#`.

[image: Rachmaninoff Prelude Op. 3 No. 2 m. 21]

Answer (score 1):

> *Bar 21 starts with A and ends with A. The final resolution to the A seems to be a d diminished seventh chord. Why has this to be a d? What is the reason or explanation behind this?*

This passage (measure) is cadencing (I-ii-viidim7-I)  in  A - the sub-mediant key of c#-minor.
Mind the pedal note.

Comment: Submediant. Mediant is E.

Comment: ok. there are 3 mediants, the upper=A and the lower. aha, you differ  supper- and submediant: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submediante